# How in terraform dynamodb specify composite primary key (hashkey)

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My goal is to create terraform `resource "aws_dynamodb_table"` with composite primary key as it describes in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey).

Based on [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dynamodb_table#hash_key) it allows for `hash_key` to have only a single Attribute name. How can I have a `hash_key` made by multiple attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `range_key` terraform argument, which is the sort key on DynamoDB. That way you'll get a composite key as stated in the AWS documentation. The `hash_key` is referred as Partition key.

> Partition key and sort key – Referred to as a composite primary key, this type of key is composed of two attributes. The first attribute is the partition key, and the second attribute is the sort key.

If you want to query among other attributes, try with a `local_secondary_index`.